# Translating short ASM snippet with pointers into C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

This is a homework-related question; I'm not looking for an exact answer, but more for some pointers as to how I could solve my problem.

In short, I am tasked with translating the snippet of ASM below into C code :

```
fct:
    movl 4(%esp), %edx   ;L1
    movl (%edx), %ebx    ;L2
    movl 4(%edx), %eax   ;L3
    addl %ebx,%eax       ;L4
    ret                  ;L5
```

First, the signature of `fct`, which I know to be correct is `int fct(int *a)`. Next, here's a brief description of what I think each line does :

- L1: put the value of the first argument of `fct` (which I'll call `arg`) into register `edx`,
- L2 : put the value at the address pointed to by register `edx` into register `ebx` (i.e. `arg[0]`),
- L3 : put the value at the address 'address pointed to by register `edx` + 4 bytes' into register `eax` (i.e. `arg[4]`),
- L4 : put the value 'value in register `eax` + value in register `ebx`' into register `eax` (i.e. `arg[4] + arg[0]`),
- L5 : return the value in register `eax` (i.e. `arg[4] + arg[0]`).

Which, translated into some pseudo-C-ish code would look something like this :

```
fct(*arg) {
    d = arg
    b = *d
    a = *(d + 4)
    a = a + b
    return a
}
```

Finally, here's the C code I came up with; I tried to format and write it so that it's as close to the original assembly as possible.

```
int fct(int *arg) {
    int *d = arg;
    int b = *d;
    int a = *(d + 0x4);
    a += b;
    return z;
}
```

I've spent the past hour trying to get this to work, but my code only works on one of the five automated tests it should pass (which I don't have access to). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: C pointer arithmetic is in units of the type pointed to, not bytes.  So if `int` is 4 bytes, then you want `d+1`, not `d+0x4`.

Comment: Yes, I just found the answer to my question after re-reading it. I need to change that `d + 0x4` to `d + 0x1`. Thank you.

Comment: The C this would come from would probably look more like: `return b[0] + b[1];`

Answer (score 0):

C pointer arithmetic is in units of the type pointed to, not bytes.  So since `int` is 4 bytes on x86-32, you want `d+1`, not `d+0x4`.